# Validate each read byte array buffer while reading a file

Tags: java, file, io, character

I'm trying to read a file using the known 'read' method by the `FileInputStream` class into a certain `byte[]` buffer with a specific size (e.g 1024). Right after filling that buffer I'd like to validate it's characters (lets say one by one) but I don't want to convert it to a String (or use regex) since I might lose data.

Could anyone advice me what's the best way doing that specific validation?
*Note: I know I can use `Character.isLetter` and such methods but I'm not sure how to iterate that buffer.*

Comment: what _exactly_ do you mean by "validate it's characters"?

Comment: just do it without conversion to a String. you have acces to the bytes...

Comment: the validation can be checking if each character is an alphabetic character

Answer (score 0):

I think this should cover what you want to do:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[1024];
int len = System.in.read(arr);
while (len != -1)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    System.out.println((char)arr[i] + " - " + Character.isLetter((char)arr[i]));
  len = System.in.read(arr);
}
```